# How can I check if hyphen or @ exists in string and get it?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string that is written in two formats . Either `"bill - nick"` or `"bill @ nick"`.I want to get the two names from the string  and store them in an array.I can try the `split()` function but I am looking for something dynamic no matter the divider the names have .

I would appreciate your help .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The divider in `split()` can be a regular expression. So use a regular expression that matches both `-` and `@`.

```js
function split_names(string) {
  return string.split(/\s*[-@]\s*/);
}

console.log(split_names("bill - nick"));
console.log(split_names("bill @ nick"));
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using `match()`:

```js
var input = "bill - nick";  // also works with "bill @ nick"
var names = input.match(/\w+/g);
console.log(names);
```